# Fill SERFF template XLSM File using C# EPPLUS library?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus, vba

How to fill the SERFF template containing MACROS using EPPLUS Library.
When i tried to edit template using this code the SERFF template crashes
here is code i am using for editing and exporting template we can get SERFF template from here http://www.serff.com/plan_management_data_templates.htm

```
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(@"D:\FFM Sharred\SERFF-PlansBenefits.xlsm");

ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile);

var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

ws.SetValue("B2", "33333");

Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12";           
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=Sample4.xlsm");
```

Comment: When I open Excel sheet I get this error Excel completed file level validation and repair. Some parts of this workbook may have been repaired or discarded.
Removed Part: /xl/vbaProject.bin part.  (Visual Basic for Applications (VBA))

Comment: The file you link to is an xlsx, not an xlsm; how did you convert it?

Comment: @Ernie i am refering this file Plan Benefits and it is xlsm with macro enabled http://www.serff.com/documents/plan_management_data_templates_plans_benefits.xlsm

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

1. Create xlsm template with macros saved
2. Make a copy of it
3. Fill the copy with required data
4. Execute the macros after filling the data in copied excel.

   ```
   FileInfo templateFile = new FileInfo(@"D:\DOTNET\navigatetest.xlsm");
   FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(@"D:\DOTNET\navigatetest11.xlsm");
   if (newFile.Exists)
   {
       newFile.Delete();
       newFile = new FileInfo(@"D:\DOTNET\navigatetest11.xlsm");
   }
   using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFile, templateFile))
   {
       ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
       String ConnectionString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=excelmaps;UID=root;PASSWORD=;";
       MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
       connection.Open();
       MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * FROM `sheet1`", connection);
       MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       dt.Load(reader);
       DataRow row1 = dt.NewRow();
       worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);       
       package.Save();
   ```

   }